# Values from string to listview using simplecursoradapter in Android, java?

Tags: java, android, listview

Giving an example, I have a table with columns look like this:

```
_id  |  Name
1.   | ExampleName_1
2.   | ExampleName_2
```

And I display values of names in my listview using simplecursoradapter like this:

```
String[] from = new String[] {cat.KEY_CAT_NAME}; 
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.l_cat};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_list,cursor,from,to,0);
listCats.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And what I want to do is set two int with values

```
int valueId1 = 40;
int valueId2 = 30;
```

I want to display this values in listview next to column cat_name.
So I need to somehow modify my `simplecursoradapter` and put my int values into array or table?

```
String[] from = new String[] {cat.KEY_CAT_NAME, myvalues?}; 
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.l_cat, R.id.l_values};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_list,cursor,from,to,0);
listCats.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I do that?

I need this because I am going to put progressBar in my listview, and these values will set progress.

Comment: so you need 3 columns: "_id  |  Name | Progress" and in order to update the `ProgressBar` you would need to setup `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`

Comment: I can't make another column in my table. Actually I will set int values from different table.

Comment: then join those two tables: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Comment: Ok, if there's no other way, I'll try it. Thank you.